# Plot of ||X||infinity norm

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

Can anybody tell me why the plot of $\|X\|_{\infty}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ comes out to be square? Since $\|(x_1,x_2)\|_{\infty} = \max\{|x_1|,|x_2|\}$, then let us say $|x_1|$ is max. Why the plot is square?

Comment: Are you asking why an open ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ looks graphically like a square under the $\|\cdot \|_{\infty}$-norm? Certainly given a single point $(x_1, x_2)$, the norm $\|(x_1,x_2)\|_{\infty}$ is just some non-negative number.

Comment: Following Tom's approach you might also look at the $X_1$ norm.  All the norms except for the usual $X_2$ give a unit ball of odd shape.

Answer (score 4):

Let's look at the boundary of a ball around the origin $(0,0)$ of radius $1$. That is, let's consider the set
$$
\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\,:\,\max\{|x|,|y|\} = 1\}
$$
You must believe that if $\max\{|x|,|y|\} = 1$ then either $|x|=1$ and $|y|\leq 1$ or $|y|=1$ and $|x|\leq 1$. So let's rewrite the set as
$$
\{ (-1, y) : -1 \leq y \leq 1 \} \cup \{(1,y) : -1\leq y \leq 1\} \cup \{(x,-1) : -1 \leq x \leq 1\} \cup \{(x,1):-1\leq x \leq 1\}
$$
But, what you might now notice is that we've divided the set into four sets, each of which is a side of the square around the origin. Hopefully this example is convincing why open/closed balls in $\mathbb{R}^2$ under the $\|\cdot \|_{\infty}$ norm do, in fact, look like squares.